# Visual Basic/Excel - Multiple equivelancies?

Tags: excel, vba

Simple question: Can I have multiple values in an equation such as:

```
x = y = z = 25
```

Note: This is for Excel macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: "no".

Sample code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim z As Integer

    x = 1
    y = 1
    z = 1

    x = y = z = 25

    Cells(1, 1).value = x
    Cells(2, 1).value = y
    Cells(3, 1).value = z
End Sub
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
```

Explanation:

In VBA, there is no == operator, so the line is interpreted as a string of boolean expressions, the end result of which is assigned to x:

```
x = (y = (z = 25))
x = (y = FALSE)
x = (FALSE)
```

y and z are left unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. I  think that would evaluate to `x = False`, since
 `z = 25` is False, `y = False` is probalbly False.
So you would assign False to x.